# My node express param is two words long - how to do I put the two words together?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node express endpoint that uses parameters.

```
    app.get('/api/viewevents/:category', ec.getEventsByCat)

    getEventsByCat: (req, res, next) => {
    let {params} = req;
    console.log(req.params.category)
    req.app.get('db').get_events_by_category([req.params.category])
        .then(events => res.status(200).send(events))
        .catch(() => res.status(500).send());
},
```

When I make a call to my endpoint with a one-word parameter, it comes back successfully. Some of my potential parameters are more than one word though, I'm trying to find the right syntax for keeping two stringing the two words together.

For example, a request to:

```
    '/api/viewevents/infrastructure'
```

or

```
    '/api/viewevents/environmental'
```

works perfectly, but a request like this does not...

```
  '/api/viewevents/household+tasks'
```

or

```
    '/api/viewevents/disaster+relief'
```

Probably not googling it the right way to get the answer I'm looking for

Comment: The + suggest this is some kind of user generated route (ie search parameters) in which case: use a query argument instead, `api/viewevents?search=distaster+relief` and then get all the words (no matter how many) from the search query instead.

Comment: So I tried doing this...

accessing the endpoint in postman via '/api/viewevents?category=household+tasks'.

the endpoint:
app.get('/api/viewevents', ec.getEventsByCat);

function:
getEventsByCat: (req, res, next) => {
        let {query} = req;
        console.log(req.query.category)
        req.app.get('db').get_events_by_category([req.query.category])
            .then(events => res.status(200).send(events))
            .catch(() => res.status(500).send());
    },

but it doesn't work... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind - got it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
app.get('/endpoint/:var1/:var2', function(req, res) {
    var data = {
        "data": {
            "var1": req.params.var1,
            "var2": req.params.var2
        }
    }; 

    send.json(data);
});
```

so in your case

```
app.get('/api/viewevents/:category1/:category2', ec.getEventsByCat)

getEventsByCat: (req, res, next) => {
let {params} = req;
console.log(req.params.category1)
req.app.get('db').get_events_by_category([req.params.category1])
    .then(events => res.status(200).send(events))
    .catch(() => res.status(500).send());
},
```

You will have to make more changes to make your code properly handle two variables for the functionality you would like